# while loop logic issue in tail grep

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, sh

I have a log file. I am doing tail -f and doing grep options whenever new logs is coming. It is working fine but the problem is in map-reduce environment,the query will distribute multiple time.So If I run one query it distributes to multiple nodes and I am getting multiple output files. I need a help to avoid this issue. here is my script.

```
EnterpriseID=55302
AuditTypeID=$""
QueryResult=$""
tail -n 0 -F hive-server2.log | \
while read LINE
do
elif [ `echo "$LINE" | grep -c 'select count' ` -gt 0 ]
then
AuditTypeID=22
QueryResult="$(grep -oE 'select count\(.\) from [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*' hive-server2.log | sed -n \$p)"
fi
Additional_Info=$(echo -e "{ \"query\":\"""${QueryResult}""\",\"\"AuditTypeID\":\"""${\"AuditTypeID}""\"}")
echo -e "$Additional_Info" > op.json
current_time=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S")
boto-rsync op.json s3://hive-log/log/script/op.json.$current_time
done
```

Sample Input - " select count(*) from table"
sample output - 1 output file only

Current output - If I execute 1 query, I am getting 12-15 output files. Because query is distributed to multiple nodes.

Expected output - If I execute 1 query (ex: select count(*) from table) . It should create 1 output file only. any help to achieve this logic would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post sample inputs and sample outputs in your post too, so that we could understand your question more clearly too.

Comment: I have posted the sample input and output

Comment: Please think about your real issue in relation to the tags you've chosen. You'll know best, but from my reading of the question it seems like awk, sed, grep, etc. have little to do with how many files are returned from executing a query. Meanwhile, the most relevant technology here seems to be `hive`, for which there's no tag at all. (It's a small thing, but could be the difference between getting the right people looking at your question or not.)

Comment: Please read this: http://bencane.com/2014/06/06/8-tips-for-creating-better-bash-scripts/  or any other bash coding style.  Indentation is crucial to help understand your code.

Comment: No, you haven't posted sample input and output, you've posted a **description** of sample input and output. Post something we can run a possible solution script against and then diff that tools output against the output you provided to tell definitively if it works or not.

Comment: Post for us a (sanitized) example 'hive-server2.log' and the output you are getting (in a couple pastebins?).  One thing that looks fishy in your script is the `elif`.  From your description, tailing directly into an awk script is probably what you want to do... You could use the strategy where you filter the input down with `sub(/pattern/, output)` and keep track of the filtered `output` in an `array` index -- along the lines of: `if (!(output in array)) { print output; array[output]="" }`

Answer (score 1):

With regard to:

```
while read LINE
do
elif [ `echo "$LINE" | grep -c 'select count' ` -gt 0 ]
then
AuditTypeID=22
QueryResult="$(grep -oE 'select count\(.\) from [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*' hive-server2.log | sed -n \$p)"
fi
```

that is *not* valid syntax. You have a "naked" `elif` in your code, one without a preceding `if`. Since `elif` is shorthand for `else if`, it *requires* a preceding `if` section.

If you only have that one condition you want checked, it should just be an `if`.

Comment: Hi sorry in the above example I missed the if part. Actually I have mentioned if and elif part.